# TinyMCE in django-cms

Tags: django, tinymce, django-cms

I'm trying to make django-cms use TinyMCE as the text editor instead of the default Wymedit. It should be an [easy job according to the docs](https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.4.0.rc1/getting_started/plugin_reference.html#text), but I just end up with an empty div instead of the editor if I follow them. I also added `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>` to `admin/base.html` template and the js file is included, but it doesn't work.

Any idea of a simple way to make it work?

---

Details:

Versions:

- Django: 1.4.5
- django-cms: 2.3.1
- django-tinymce: 1.4

What I did (I followed the [django-cms docs](https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.1/getting_started/plugin_reference.html#text)):

- added to `settings.py`:

`TINYMCE_JS_URL = 'http://mysite.com/media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js'`

`TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = 'http://mysite.com/media/js/tiny_mce/'`

`CMS_USE_TINYMCE = True`

- added `tinymce` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`
- added `(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls'))` to `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`
- added to `templates/admin.base.html`:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>`

(this step was not in the docs this is the only way I got `tiny_mce.js` to load in the browser)

- copied tinymce files to `MEDIA_ROOT`

Comment: Do you get some errors like 404 that the sources are be not foundable.

Comment: no 404, no other error, tiny_mce.js loads fine in the browser, no other javascript errors... but I get an empty div instead of the editor (not even a textarea, just an empty div!)

Comment: @Azd325 do you have any idea about where should I start in trying to solve this? what to check for? ...I'm newish to Django and new to django-cms and I'm completely stuck on this, I have no idea where to start from, it's like hitting a brick wall...

Comment: hmm, i am not used to Django, but can you verify that a tinymce.init({...}) gets called on your page?

Comment: TinyMce if you start every time tricky. Can you make sure you have everything from the docs. That we can exclude some miss configuration.
Maybe you can post the parts what you did? Also is should be nice if show which django cms/ django / tinymce library(version) you use!

Comment: @Azd325 I've posted more details above. Right now I'm just trying to make the django admin use tinymce, pretending that django-cms doesn't even exists since it's obvious that its docs are crap and it's doing too much weird stuff...

Comment: @Azd325 did the painful upgrade to django-cms 2.4.0... now I don't get the empty DIV, but I get the old Wymeditor instead of TinyMCE...

Comment: Do you added (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')), to your urls?

Comment: @Azd325 yep, that too (forgot to write in the detailed description above, sorry)

Comment: @Azd325 thanks for all. it finally works after I did a proper upgrade of everything and fixed some unrelated errors. I don't know why it didn't work (and I don't know why it works - I even removed the line from admin/base.html that loads tiny_mce.js and it still works, also removed the js files from the media folder and still works - guess django-cms does some black magick and pulls in tinymce js together with its scripts)... I guess it's time to either ditch django-cms for good (too much magic), or sit down and review its code line by line, hopefully learn a lot about django in the process

Answer (score 1):

So I tried also again to install django tinymce on my own.

This code I included in my installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'tinymce',
    'cms.plugins.text',
)
```

And this code to my url patterns

```
(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
```

And is working in my dev enviroment. The other configuration points are optional

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised you do not get 404 errors. AFAIK django-cms and django-tinymce look in the static files location, not media.
Therefore to get tinymce installed I needed to run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Maybe this helps. If not, it may help someone else looking at this question

Comment: He was  probably in debug mode.(I think he was setup this urls for serving http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.4.0/getting_started/tutorial.html#url-configuration in debug mode)

This command, you was using is only for collect static files to one single place. Like if you go in production mode(DEBUG = False) and then you have to setup you webserver to serve this folder.

And he was solving it on his own.

Comment: Be the previous comment as it may, he was *right* and it *helped*. So I think you were a little harsh.